# How does game guardian collects data from?

Tags: rooting, shell, ram

I have a rooted android phone, I just only wanted to know how to get apps Variable values by using the android shell.

Comment: Would you clarify `apps Variable`?

Comment: Like the value of no. of coins in a game, or any string value, or any data stored in memory address

Comment: Those must be saved in some kind of database in app's data folder, may be encrypted and not simply readable.

Comment: "Game Guardian" sounds more like an app that scans and manipulates app data in-memory. This requires knowledge of the general in-memory structure of Linux processes. A generic manipulation tool that can be accessed from a PC would be [Frida](https://www.frida.re/docs/android/).

Comment: Thank you for telling me about Frida, but i want variable values, not manipulating functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by scanning the /data/data/com.example.app/ database file's...

- You select the game, or it grabbs the active application from running applications.
- It uses the selected package name like so ...

  grep (options) "/data/data/"+com.example.app+"/*.dbs"

It searches the text of all (.*) databases and sometimes other files like configuration files..

If multiple of the number you are searching for is found, then it will ask you to change the number ( buy something - Make your money value change ) Now it will check the lines in the dstabase that it found the first search at, and look for difference's...

So lets say you had 100 dollars in-game ... Your initial search for 100 gives 5 results in various places...

You buy something and your value changes to say 95..

The app uses a grep or similar command to search the 5 initial results and see what has changed to 95 .... When it locates the line responsible for the 100 to 95 change, it has located your Money Value in the game databases .... Now you can manipulate that line to say 1,000,000 ... When you restart the game, you'll have the additional money ...

This is a very old form of game hacking and these days, you can just buy the money from Google Play without paying anything by using an Intent Override...

The game asks you to complete the purchase in Google Play, Instead you can intercept the request and automatically accept the payment as-if it was successful...

If you are interested in that avenue, have a look at LuckyPatcher.apk ... I will not provide a link due to the nature of the application, you'll need to find that yourself.